# FIFO code explanation

Tags: java

Is the following code an example of a FIFO ordering?

The problem consists of implementing a FIFO queue.

In a nutshell: a random number of cars (going north or south) drive along a two lane road.
They must traverse a bridge which is one way.

The bridge access is dependent on the arrival time. First come First served.

Can I say that through this statement

```
semaphore = new Semaphore(capacita,true);
```

cars cross the bridge according their arrival order?

Here I can't figure out how it works and how it can be related to the previous statement

```
lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Can someone help me?

thanks

```
public Ponte(int capacita){
        nNordTraversing = 0;    
        nSudTraversing = 0;     
        nNordWaiting = 0;   
        nSudWaiting = 0;    

        semaphore = new Semaphore(capacita,true); 


        lock = new ReentrantLock(true);           

        waitingCond = lock.newCondition();
        bridgeCond = lock.newCondition();
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to do anything right now

Comment: I don't think it does anything (other than initialise some member variables).

Comment: @ControlAltDel: LIFO would be an annoying way to cross a bridge...

Comment: @ControlAltDel: I don't think the problem requires a lifo (stack). That should definitely be a FIFO. Basically first one to arrive grabs the semaphore, traverses when the semaphore is obtained, then it's the next one in line. FIFO

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I meant FIFO

Comment: Looks like a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

your code is strange, and i don't understand them just with this part.
You can easily found a correct algorithm on the internet for resolve that with semaphore.

for example : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/119766-semaphore-algorithm.html
this problem looks like your!
Good luck for searching!